# How to limit floating numbers in runif in R?

Tags: r

I have a few problems.

1 - How to limit the number of floating numbers in `runif` function in R? For example, I use the code below to generate a matrix.

```
n1 = runif(10,1,5)
n2 = runif(10,1,6)
n3 = runif(10,1,7)
n4 = runif(10,1,8)
numvect=list(transpose(n1),transpose(n2),transpose(n3),transpose(n4))
#put the number vectors into a matrix
# construct a matrix with 10 rows and 4 columns

matrixnum = matrix(,nrow=10,ncol=4)
for(i in 1:8){
  matrixnum[,i] <- numvect[[i]]
}
write.table(matrixnum,'num4.txt',sep = "\t",row.names=F,col.names=F,options(digits=4)) # write the matrix
```

But in the results, it still have 14 or 15 floating numbers. I think the `options(digits=4)` argument doesn't work here.

2 - When writing a matrix to a .txt output, how to control the numbers in the file to be not of scientific notation?

Comment: `round(x, 4)` will round the values in `x` to 4 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: but will to apply in the code?

Comment: For your second question (for which you can easily find an asnwer btw), see this: `format(1e-6, scientific = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to turn the four random-number vectors into a 10x4 matrix rounded to four decimals places, I think you can just do this:

```
n1 = runif(10,1,5)
n2 = runif(10,1,6)
n3 = runif(10,1,7)
n4 = runif(10,1,8)

matrixnum = matrix(round(c(n1,n2,n3,n4), 4), nrow=10)
```

Another option to convert the values into a matrix is the following. This might be easier in this case, since you know you want each of your vectors to be a column and this avoids having to worry about setting `nrow` or `ncol` correctly in `matrix()`:

```
round(as.matrix(cbind(n1,n2,n3,n4)), 4)
```

Then, to write the matrix to a file:

```
write.table(matrixnum, 'num4.txt', sep = "\t", row.names=F, col.names=F)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. it seems i wrote many useless code. do you know how to solve the second problem? the second problem is not related to runif function.

Comment: When I write the numbers to a text file on my computer, they are written in decimal representation, rather than in scientific notation. If you're seeing the numbers in scientific notation in R, you might try adjusting the `scipen` option. It's an integer and the default is zero. Higher values will reduce the likelihood of a number being printed in scientific notation.

Comment: Also, for future reference, as far as I know, there's no `transpose()` function in R. To transpose a matrix, the function is `t()`.

Comment: Thanks. I just see transpose() still works right now, but t() is more easy and clean.